# Angular 16 - Bind component input to route param from parent route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Imagine a component (`some.component.ts`) in Angular 16 which takes value for its `foo` property from `activeRoute` - but from the **parent route**. See the example below:

```
@Input() foo!: string;

constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.foo = this.activeRoute.parent?.snapshot.params['foo'];
}
```

I would like to use the Angular 16 input binding to route params here. It works for other cases but I am not sure how to make it working when the param actually comes from a parent route.

The routes look like this:

```
{
  path: 'bar/:foo',
  component: IrrelevantComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'some',
      component: SomeComponent,
    },
  ],
},
```

Is this even possible to achieve using the new route param binding? If so then how?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

Answer (score 5):

@skink's comment links to the docs which how to do this: https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

> If you want to use the parent components route info you will need to set the router paramsInheritanceStrategy option: `withRouterConfig({paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'})`